# Liferay returns a blank page

Tags: liferay

So I plugged in the following connection to our SQL Server database below, but it's rendering a blank page when I start the server

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mywebsite.com:15001;databaseName=Liferay
jdbc.default.username=user
jdbc.default.password=pass
```

Specs:
Liferay 6.2
WebLogic 12c App Server

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Any error log in tomcat console?

Comment: @Clay can you give more input to your question.